# htaccess query_string and rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hello guys I'm using this htaccess script to set `search.php?q=sometng&type=all` to `search/sometng/`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} q=(.*)&type=all

RewriteRule ^search\.php$  /search\/%1\/? [R=301,L]
```

it works succesfully BUT I GET 404 error!

I've tried to put

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/$ search.php?q=$1&type=all
```

it returns Attempting to open is not going to end any time entered into a routing loop.

whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-z][A-Z])/([a-z][A-Z])/$ /search.php?q=$1&type=$2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ search.php?q=$1&type=$2 [L]
```